# jQuery animate current list items

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/hQnXm/7/

So basically i need when hover, it should animate only that li item images. Currently it animates all li images globally.

Comment: Please be a lot more specific about what your question is.  What are expectWhat have you investigated so far?  The phrase "current list item images" is unclear what it means.  It is not clear what you intend for the result to be?  You have two places to hover.  It is not clear which one you're asking about?  You have to make your question a lot clearer.  You've essentially posted a link to your code and asked us to fix it.  That's not how StackOverflow works.

Comment: so basically i need when hover, it should animate only that li item images. Currently it animates all li images globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way the code currently works, each set of `<li>` tags needs to be in it's own `<ul class="box">` for the code to work like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YT2LG/

Or, you can change this line of code:

```
var top = self.closest(".box");
```

to this:

```
var top = self.closest(".item");
```

to get the code to work with the HTML you have as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/DjtKS/

Answer (score 1):

How about selecting:

```
var top = self.closest(".item");
```

Instead of `.box`.

By selecting the `li.item` you can also replace your calls to `find` with [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/).